# Default constructor cannot be referenced -- It's a deleted function in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I try to compile the code from https://github.com/zcbenz/BPlusTree in Visual Studio 2015 Community. The code can be compiled in gcc, but in VS, I got

> the default constructor of "bpt::internal_node_t" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

the structure goes like this:

```
struct internal_node_t {
    typedef index_t * child_t;

    off_t parent; /* parent node offset */
    off_t next;
    off_t prev;
    size_t n; /* how many children */
    index_t children[BP_ORDER];
};
```

references can be seen everywhere in `bpt.cc`, like this

```
internal_node_t parent;
```

I don't really get what the message means. How to make the code compiled in VS?

some type definition update:

```
struct key_t {
    char k[16];

    key_t(const char *str = "")
    {
        bzero(k, sizeof(k));
        strcpy_s(k, str);
    }
};
typedef unsigned int     size_t;

struct index_t {
    key_t key;
    off_t child; /* child's offset */
};
```

I use `off_t` in `<sys\types.h>` and a marco `#define bzero(ptr, size) memset(ptr, 0, size)` for `bzero`

I also write another program like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define bzero(ptr, size) memset(ptr, 0, size)

struct key_t {
    char k[16];

    key_t(const char *str = "")
    {
        bzero(k, sizeof(k));
        strcpy_s(k, str);
    }
};
struct index_t {
    key_t key;
    off_t child; /* child's offset */
};



struct internal_node_t {
    typedef index_t * child_t;

    off_t parent; /* parent node offset */
    off_t next;
    off_t prev;
    size_t n; /* how many children */
    index_t children[20];
};

int main() {
    internal_node_t t;
}
```

That works in VS2015.

Comment: omg present a TESTCASE - we have a whole bunch of unknown types here. What are we supposed to do with those????!?!?!?!?!?!??!?!

Comment: There is no way I'm going to load `BPlusTree` onto my computer to build and test for you.  I have no idea of the dangers involved.

Comment: I update some code definition, I really don't know how to present a testcase, error happened when `internal_node_t` initialized

Comment: `typedef unsigned int     size_t;` - you should not write this in your code. Instead include `<stdlib.h>` or some other standard header

Comment: You are passing the wrong number of arguments to `strcpy_s`

Answer (score 2):

I find it unlikely that a codebase that relies on POSIX types will compile in a compiler that targets Windows. Maybe you should try something like Cygwin.

For example, both `off_t` and `key_t` come from `<sys/types.h>`. The author didn't even bother including this header, giving a false sense of portability.

NOTE: [VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k.aspx) does have `off_t`. It seems the actual issue is System V IPC (`<sys/ipc.h>`, the actual header that cares about `key_t`) which is linux specific.

Comment: I update some type definitions. `key_t` seems not related to `<sys/ipc.h>`?